# Running more than one application context with embedded jetty

Tags: java, spring, jetty

I'm currently using the `Spring` framework as an IoC container for a stand-alone `Java` application. This stand-alone `Java` application uses `WebSockets` to publish information to a `Spring` `MVC` web application.

Both the stand-alone app and the web app use Jetty. Both apps run on the same dedicated server with no connection to an external LAN.

If the web app is not active then I don't need `WebSockets` or `Jetty` running.

The question is, do I simply treat them as two distinct applications/contexts and embed jetty into each?